# Issue with CORS after adding Stormpath Angular SDK

Tags: angularjs, cors, stormpath

I am working on SPA MEAN app, I was developing it against Apiary mock APIs, which has the following CORS headers set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,TRACE,CONNECT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Max-Age → 10
```

It all works fine and angular can access it using $http angular service just fine. However after adding Stormpath Angular SDK all these requests fail with following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx.apiary-mock.com/workshops?type=favourite. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am trying to get to figure out why these requests are rejected and at what point these headers are added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for finding this issue.  The Stormpath Angular SDK does have an interceptor which sets the `withCredentials: true` flag for all requests.  Please see the code [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/blob/master/src/module.js#L98-L101).

The intention is to ensure that our authentication cookies are always sent, even in a cross-domain situation.  But I can see how this will be problematic if your Angular application is talking to other APIs that don't require cookies to be sent.

As a workaround, you can override our interceptor by simply adding another one:

```
angular.module('myapp', [
  'stormpath',
  'stormpath.templates'
]).config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
      request: function(config) {
        config.withCredentials=false;
        return config;
      }
    };
  });
});
```

I've created an issue to discuss a better solution: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/issues/72

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted! Thanks also for raising an issue, hopefully that will be a configurable thing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have a SPA client served from one domain (e.g. `localhost:8080`) and you want that client to access an API on another domain (`xxx.apiary-mock.com`), the browser requires that the server domain add [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers correctly.

If the client and server domains are different, the browser's security model requires the server to indicate which client domains may access the server by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header (in addition to other relevant `Access-Control-*` headers).

Comment: I understand that, what I wonder where in the Stormpath client framework it makes 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header required and is it possible to disable this check.

Comment: @Vitalij ah, great clarification - thanks! I'll ping our JS SDK team and ask them to assist here.

Answer (score 0):

I have how to work around it add these headers to apiary:

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)

    + Headers

            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,TRACE,CONNECT
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
```

I am still trying to figure out where does Stormpath make those headers required though.